# When using the function boxCox in R I keep getting this error "Error in as.data.frame.default(

Tags: r, lm

I have the correct package alr4 which contains cars so it shouldn't be a problem with the function itself

```
box <- lm(Distance~Speed, data = stop)
boxCox(box)
```

This is the error

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(data, optional = TRUE) : cannot coerce class ‘"function"’ to a data.frame
```

The `lm` function runs  just fine on its own, and I have used it in other analysis just fine, so it isn't an issue there. I am mostly just confused about the error and how to fix it. If you have suggestions or know why it happens that would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: `stop` is a function in R. I think it is getting confused because of that. Try renaming the dataframe to something else and try again.

Comment: That fixed it thanks!

Comment: The 'alr4' package does not have a `boxCox` function.

Comment: I think it works because it includes the package car which does